# Mysterious White Space at bottom of Web Page in Mobile-Chrome

Tags: html, css, viewport, mobile-chrome

I've looked at many "mysterious white-space at bottom of page" issues here on SO, and played with the `viewport`tag many times, but I still cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong!

The page in question is: http://www.seniorchoicesunl.com/error_documents/error401.php

Here's what it looks like on mobile from Chrome Dev Tools:[image]

Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

setting *ANY* `initial-scale` is bad news! It makes the font too tiny!
Take a look:
[image]

The desired mobile look, while keeping the desktop and tablets as-is, is this:

[image]

P.S. Fixing this issue could reciprocally fix other related issues I'm having with other webpages.

Comment: Try height : some value greater than mobile devices length

Comment: I cannot set an exact height or the page would not be responsive for screen rotations. There has to be a more intelligent standards-compliant way.

Comment: Can you turn off that auto-redirect while for a while? It's annoying having to hit the back button every 30 seconds.

Comment: Will do! Let me do that right now! Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: Auto-redirect temporarily commented out (i.e. disabled)!

Comment: @Miro Unfortunately that's not 100% true, because it happens on my Samsung Galaxy S5 phone, but looks fine on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S (that also follows mobile viewport rules).

Answer (score 19):

Add this on top of your css file :)

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

it fixed the bug for me.

Comment: holy crap, seems like this fixed the bug - i was searching a looong time to fix it.

Comment: BUT for ios you need to remove overflow-x: hidden; bcs you cant scroll smooth

Comment: you are awesome! this fixed it for me as well

Comment: I had the same problem but I could not set `overflow-x: hidden` because I need to scroll horizontally on my page. If you have the same problem, try setting `overflow-x: auto`, it fixed the blank space while still allowing me to scroll (no idea why).

Answer (score 4):

What's going on here:

- You've set `width=device-width`, this makes the layout size on your page equal to the device's screen width. i.e. making an element 100% will give it the same width as the screen.
- Chrome infers the layout height using the width and screen's aspect ratio. i.e. height=width/aspectRatio
- The sub_container_div element actually ends up being much wider than the layout width of the page. In my case on a Nexus 6, the device-width is 412px while the sub_container_div is 594px wide.
- Since the content is wider than device-width, Chrome allows zooming out and loads the page at the minimum zoom level but this doesn't change the layout width/height so height 100% only fills `device-width/aspect ratio` pixels, which doesn't fill the zoomed out viewport.

The correct way to fix this is to make sure all your content is contained by the layout size. In your case, the reason the sub_container_div is wider than the layout size is that your padding/margins cause it to expand outside the parent. The solution is to add `box-sizing: border-box` to the sub_container_div and dialog elements and `width: 100%` to sub_container_div. That way, Chrome can't zoom out and you can't see outside the layout box (in HTML spec language, that's the initial containing block).

Comment: Just tried it that way, adding `max-width:37em;` to keep the desired, consistent, horizontal rectangle shape on desktop. On mobile, though, it looks kind of odd though, because the letters are pretty big, and the standard rectangular message box shape is transformed into an elongated one.

Comment: The initial-scale did eventually help ( `initial-scale:0.7` was perfect!).This question has been officially solved (for the sake of the "Perfect Error Docs" script. And I will immediately update that script with the newly responsive, and mobile-friendly code. Though, It may not work the same for everyone), by a combination of answers provided. But yours was the most descriptive, and comprehensive, so if you would just add the extra code I used, to make it all work, I will gladly mark your answer as the chosen, and correct one! Thanks David!

Comment: Actually, spoke too fast. Now it looks too small on tablets! :-( I'm testing with Samsung Galaxy Tab S.

Comment: If `initial-scale:0.7` is still making a difference, you've still got content that's wider than the initial containing block and you're masking the problem by zooming out. You should make sure all your elements are contained by the `<body>` element in DevTools by hovering over body and seeing if anything is outside its box. Depending on the effect you want to achieve, it may be worth using media queries to change font/dialog size based on screen size.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is that by allowing zooming out, the browser enters a mode meant for legacy desktop pages and has poor interop between browsers and quirky features. Try adding `minimum-scale=1` to the viewport meta tag and work from there to get the page looking correct.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Chrome 77

I fixed the problem by removing `height: 100vh` on the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fix the problem:

1. Change `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`.
2. Override `width: 25em;` on `.sub_container_div` in your mobile CSS so that the container scales with the width of the view.

If you do not want the font to scale, it seems just adding `initial-scale=0` will work as well. However, this will make the text very hard to read. You can play around with different scales, but it seems just setting it will fix your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work because the `.sub_container_div` cannot be changed. That part of the code has already been perfected in order to keep the dialog box perfectly centered in the middle of the page (despite window width) on Desktops. I was looking for a solution that would only modify the "mobile" view of the page because everything else is nearly perfect.

Comment: Hm, it depends what you want then. If you want the view to be mobile friendly, you can certainly make a media query for small screens that overrides the desktop width without affecting how it looks on desktops. If you just want the desktop view (with tiny, not-mobile-friendly font), you can set the `initial-scale` to `0` to get the desktop view on the phone.

Comment: You can do it without media-query and still have it work on desktop: `.sub_container_div{ width:auto; max-width:25em }` In any case `initial-scale=1.0` is the way to go. Enjoy!

Comment: Did I miss something? I though we were talking about height here. The width is working perfectly fine. It fills out the page fine, on both desktop, and mobile.

Comment: The width won't work once you change your initial-scale to 1... That's what you missed ;)

Comment: @karin I already made a mobile version that works as expected here: [ http://m.seniorchoicesunl.com/error_documents/error401.php ] I'm trying to update (optimize) this [ http://www.perfecterrordocs.com/  ] script for the benefit of my own sites and everyone elses. If you're confident your way would look better maybe you could fork it on GitHub, or make a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

In my case one element was too long for a mobile screen and it broke the webflow. After I shortened the width of the long element, the extra white screen was also removed from the footer.