# Can you control mobile Chrome's "inferred layout height" (for horizontal layouts)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

Lacking better terms for the problem, this question got a bit long. Sorry!

I've been trying to build a simple horizontal layout with a bunch of `<div>`s with `width: 100%; height: 100%` next to each other ("screens" of an app that you can swipe).

In Chrome's responsive preview, as well as on a real device, empty space appeared below the `<div>`s — no invisible objects, no traces of the excess height in any DOM properties.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85783be24c4d891afae22cb94cf98290), [try it via bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/85783be24c4d891afae22cb94cf98290/). Scrolled all the way down, it looks like this:

[image: responsive preview]

Red/blue are the `div`s, yellow is `body`s `background-color`.

In a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39083192/629238) I found this:

> Chrome infers the layout height using the width and screen's aspect ratio. i.e. height=width/aspectRatio

Which means that **if my content is wider than the viewport, a minimal height will be calculated for it**. I find this weird, and came up with workarounds:

- set `html, body { overflow-y: hidden}`
- put *all* children of `<body>` inside a `<div>` wrapper

Since both methods have downsides or aren't always applicable, **I am wondering: is there a way to control this behavior, like, set the inferred layout height to "auto"?**