# What's this weird white-space underneath the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, debugging

While inspecting with the device toolbar in Chrome I have this weird whitespace underneath the HTML tag. The whitespace dissapears when I disable the device toolbar ... There are some other issues as well, but we'll leave those for now.

[image]

Would love to hear from you all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does ==$0 (double equals dollar zero) mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999739/what-does-0-double-equals-dollar-zero-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysterious White Space at bottom of Web Page in Mobile-Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070028/mysterious-white-space-at-bottom-of-web-page-in-mobile-chrome)

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak: that wasn't even part of the question.

Comment: @MaorRefaeli: thanks for this; sadly it didn't solve the issue. I have added the CSS code that was suggested but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexHermans There are more solutions there you could try

Comment: is your HTML 100vh ? Like this :  html, body{min-height:100%;}

Comment: Thank you @AndréDS that was it. It seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice, I'll post a more complete answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your body is 100% height, but your **HTML parent tag isn't**.

That way, your body tag take 100% height of "nothing" height. You should put an `height` or `min-height` property on parent (`<html>`) :

```
html, body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```