# css white space on the bottom of the page only on mobile version

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive design that work well but i have a problem only on mobile devices that i have a white space in the bottom of the page

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I tried to put

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
min-height: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't work

i check the css code if i have a big hight in an element but i don't have

i used the

```
*{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but also i didn't know how to fix it

i tried `margin` and `padding 0` for the `p` in the footer but also this doesn't fix the problem

online link for the website

[my website](https://mhmd2991.github.io/template-03/)

This problem appear only on the mobile device on the tablet and pcs i don't have this problem

How can i remove this white space in the bottom of the page on mobile devices?

Comment: Let me know if my solution works for you.

Comment: @AlexGru yes your solution work if i don't want to use transition thank you a lot you help me to find what cause this problem i solve it by using overflow: hidden; and every thing is fine now and i can use the transition also thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.team-section` elements are causing the overflowing layout on mobile, on desktop this isn't directly visible. They are taking some fixed space due to the `display: grid`, as you can see here in the DOM:

[image]

When you show only the `.active` element, it works as expected on both mobile and desktop.

```css
.team-section:not(.active) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The `!important` is not required if you remove the default `display: grid` from the elements.

Comment: thank you a lot you help me to find the problem i did that overflow: hidden; and i solve the problem because if i use the display: none and display: grid i can't use the transition the overflow: hidden; solve the problem in the mobile version

Comment: Okay, please accept my answer then. :)

Comment: Never use !important in your production code. Search why it is bad, but in short, it is a bad practice that goes against the cascading nature of cascading styles.

Comment: @Dima I absolutely agree, it was only meant if OP has no authorship on the original code. also see my last sentence in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the following in the top top of the CSS ? Tell me if it works

```css
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I see, I think you can find your solution here. 
[Mysterious White Space at bottom of Web Page in Mobile-Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070028/mysterious-white-space-at-bottom-of-web-page-in-mobile-chrome)

Can you check ?

Comment: thanl you for your answer i tired all of this solution but i doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Umm can you send me source code on GitHub ? HTML and CSS just to have a quick check ?

Comment: yes https://github.com/mhmd2991/template-03